# How to use alert message box using Ajax in PHP without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have my PHP code here together with the design and its back end process. What is the correct syntax in using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for using alert message that pops up when the 'createpassword' and 'confirmpassword' does not match when the user inputs a data.

I tried using the JavaScript type of alert box, but it refreshes the form whenever the user inputs a password. I want it to just display an alert box, and it won't refresh the page. Does anyone have any ideas?

This is my PHP design:

```
<?php
    $MonthArray = array(
        1=>"January",
        2=> "February",
        3=> "March",
        4=> "April",
        5=> "May",
        6=> "June",
        7=> "July",
        8=> "August",
        9=> "September",
        10=> "October",
        11=> "November",
        12=> "December",
    );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="signup">
            <form action="SignupProcess.php" method="POST">
                <!-- Complete Name -->
                <div class="Name">
                    <label><span style="font-weight:bold">Name</span></label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" size="15" placeholder="First" required>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" size="15" placeholder="Last" required>
                </div>
                <br>

                <!-- Username -->
                <div class="Username">
                    <label><span style="font-weight:bold">Choose your username</span></label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="username" size="35" required>
                </div>
                <br>

                <!-- Password -->
                <div class="Password">
                    <label><span style="font-weight:bold">Create a password</span></label><br>
                    <input type="password" name="createpassword" size="35" required>
                    <br><br>

                    <label><span style="font-weight:bold">Confirm your password</span></label><br>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" size="35" required>
                </div>
                <br>

                <!-- Birthdate -->
                <div class="Birthdate">
                    <select name="month" required>
                        <option disabled selected>Month</option>
                        <?php foreach($MonthArray as $monthkey => $value) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $monthkey ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
                        <?php }?>
                    </select>

                    <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="Day" size="5" required>

                    <select name="year" required>
                        <?php
                            foreach(range(1990, (int)date("Y")) as $year) {
                                echo "\t<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>\n\r";
                                rsort($year);
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <!-- Buttons -->
                <div class="Buttons">
                    <input type="submit" id="signup" name="signupsubmit">
                    <input type="reset" id="reset" name="signupreset">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And its PHP process:

```
<?php
    include("CreateConnection.php");

    // Get values from form Signup.php file
    $FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['firstname']);
    $LastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lastname']);
    $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
    $CreatePassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['createpassword']);
    $ConfirmPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['confirmpassword']);
    $Month = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['month']);
    $Day = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['day']);
    $Year = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['year']);

    // Removes back slashes in input
    $FirstName = stripcslashes($FirstName);
    $LastName = stripcslashes($LastName);
    $Username = stripcslashes($Username);
    $CreatePassword = stripcslashes($CreatePassword);
    $ConfirmPassword = stripcslashes($ConfirmPassword);
    $Month = stripcslashes($Month);
    $Day = stripcslashes($Day);
    $Year = stripcslashes($Year);

    if($CreatePassword != $ConfirmPassword)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password does not match please check.');</script> ";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'Signup.php'\", 0)</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        // Query Insert into tablereminders
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `tablereminders`(`username`, `password`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `Month`, `Day`, `Year`)
        VALUES ('$Username','$ConfirmPassword','$FirstName','$LastName','$Month','$Day','$Year')");
    }

    // Error connection and query
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
    {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'LoginReminder.php'\", 500)</script>";
    }
?>
```

This code here is where I will display an alert box without page refresh.

```
if($CreatePassword != $ConfirmPassword)
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password does not match please check.');</script> ";
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'Signup.php'\", 0)</script>";
}
```

I want to put an Ajax request in my SignupProcess.php. Is it okay to call the form function externally?

Comment: You should probably have the `PHP` output `JSON`, and then parse the `JSON` in your javascript and display the output that way.

Comment: I think calling `stripcslashes` after `mysqli_real_escape_string` makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. In any case, checkout prepare statements, your code will be much simpler if you use them: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to php and searching some good way to prevent sql injection I'll change it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this validation simply using JavaScript code like this:

```
<?php
    $MonthArray = array(
        1 => "January",
        2 => "February",
        3 => "March",
        4 => "April",
        5 => "May",
        6 => "June",
        7 => "July",
        8 => "August",
        9 => "September",
        10 => "October",
        11 => "November",
        12 => "December",
    );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sign up</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate_form() {

                var createpass = document.getElementById("createpassword").value;
                var confirmpass = document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;

                if (createpass != confirmpass) {

                    alert("Password does not match please check.");
                    document.getElementById("createpassword").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="signup">
                <form action="SignupProcess.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate_form();">
                    <!-- Complete Name -->
                    <div class="Name">
                        <label><span style="font-weight:bold">Name</span></label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" size="15" placeholder="First" required>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" size="15" placeholder="Last" required>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <!-- Username -->
                    <div class="Username">
                        <label><span style="font-weight:bold">Choose your username</span></label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="username" size="35" required>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div class="Password">
                        <label><span style="font-weight:bold">Create a password</span></label><br>
                        <input type="password" name="createpassword"  id="createpassword" size="35" required>
                        <br><br>

                        <label><span style="font-weight:bold">Confirm your password</span></label><br>
                        <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" size="35" required>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <!-- Birthdate -->
                    <div class="Birthdate">
                        <select name="month" required>
                            <option disabled selected>Month</option>
                            <?php foreach ($MonthArray as $monthkey => $value) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $monthkey ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>

                        <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="Day" size="5" required>

                        <select name="year" required>
                            <?php
                            foreach (range(1990, (int) date("Y")) as $year) {
                                echo "\t<option value='" . $year . "'>" . $year . "</option>\n\r";
                                rsort($year);
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Buttons -->
                    <div class="Buttons">
                        <input type="submit" id="signup" name="signupsubmit">
                        <input type="reset" id="reset" name="signupreset">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've added `id` attribute to your both password fields and then added `onsubmit="return validate_form();"` function in your form tag.

You can see that a JavaScript function was added in the head tag.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Oh, it work! thank you so much. I thought using only ajax can perform that.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Your requirement was to simply validate two passwords which not necessarily require form submission and all.